# The layout in red color Layout is not visible over the silver one

Tags: android, xml

The layout in red color Layout is not visible over the silver one. I would like to overlap the container and make visible the textview visible in above container.
Please suggest what should be the solution as marginTop=-30dp seems to work bad. Any help would be appriciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:background="#676363"
           >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:text="@string/special_offer"
                android:id="@+id/special_offer"

                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textColor="#f0eaea" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

                android:text="@string/disney_less"
                android:id="@+id/disney_less"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/special_offer"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textColor="#ef6e6e"
                android:shadowColor="#ffffff" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/choose_disney"
                android:id="@+id/choose_disney"

                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textColor="#eef7e3"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_below="@+id/disney_less"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/take_advantage"
                android:id="@+id/take_advantage"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="#191717"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="false" />
            </RelativeLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        android:background="#efefef"

        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/disney_world"
            android:id="@+id/disney_world"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:fontFamily="@string/common_google_play_services_enable_text"
            android:textColor="#0b125f" />


        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#efefef"

        >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_height="320dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

            <FrameLayout android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="#a9a9a9"

                >

                </FrameLayout>




            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
                android:background="#e4e4e4"

                >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:background="#a26262"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"
                                        >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/save_upto"
                        android:id="@+id/save_upto"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="#1c234a"
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/room_selected"
                        android:text="@string/room_selected"
                        android:textSize="12dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/great_rate"
                        android:text="@string/great_rate"
                        android:textSize="12dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="35dp"
                        android:paddingRight="35dp" />


                </LinearLayout>






            </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>


        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="#a3d5d1ef"
            android:backgroundTintMode="screen"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/more_information"
                android:id="@+id/more_information"
                android:textColor="#1c234a"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/special_saving"
                android:id="@+id/special_saving"
                android:textColor="#040404"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: also show screenshpt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I went ahead and tried to view your code by putting it in Android Studio and I got this:

[image]

The red layout is under the silver layout, which makes the *save up to* textview not visible. And by your description -- *I would like to **overlap** the container and **make visible the textview visible in above container**.* -- you want the layout with silver background to be on top of the red layout, where it shows the TextView with *Save Up to*, and if what I imagine it would like is correct, it would be something like this:

[image]

Here is the modified code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#676363">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"

                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/special_offer"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:text="Special Offer"
                        android:textColor="#f0eaea"
                        android:textSize="25dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/disney_less"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:layout_below="@+id/special_offer"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:shadowColor="#ffffff"
                        android:text="Disney Less"
                        android:textColor="#ef6e6e"
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/choose_disney"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/disney_less"

                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:text="Choose Disney"
                        android:textColor="#eef7e3"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/take_advantage"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:gravity="bottom"
                        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp"
                        android:paddingStart="10dp"
                        android:text="Take Advantage"
                        android:textColor="#191717" />
                </RelativeLayout>


            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#efefef"

            android:orientation="vertical"

            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/disney_world"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Disney World"
                android:textColor="#0b125f"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:background="#efefef"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="320dp">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="160dp"
                    android:background="#a9a9a9" />

                <!--<LinearLayout-->
                    <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                    <!--android:layout_height="160dp"-->
                    <!--android:layout_marginTop="160dp"-->
                    <!--android:background="#e4e4e4"-->
                    <!--android:orientation="vertical">-->
                <!--</LinearLayout>-->

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:background="#a26262"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/save_upto"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Save Up to"
                        android:textColor="#1c234a"
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/room_selected"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:text="Room Selected"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/great_rate"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="35dp"
                        android:paddingRight="35dp"
                        android:text="Great Rate"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />

                </LinearLayout>


            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#a3d5d1ef"
                android:backgroundTintMode="screen"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/more_information"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="More Info"
                    android:textColor="#1c234a"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/special_saving"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="Special Saving"
                    android:textColor="#040404"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Hope this helps, if ever this is not the full answer you are looking for, feel free to comment and I'll try to help as much as I can. :)

Answer (score 0):

Akshat try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#676363">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"

                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/special_offer"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:text="special_offer"
                        android:textColor="#f0eaea"
                        android:textSize="25dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/disney_less"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:layout_below="@+id/special_offer"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:shadowColor="#ffffff"
                        android:text="disney_less"
                        android:textColor="#ef6e6e"
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/choose_disney"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/disney_less"

                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:text="choose_disney"
                        android:textColor="#eef7e3"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/take_advantage"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:gravity="bottom"
                        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                        android:paddingStart="10dp"
                        android:text="ake_advantage"
                        android:textColor="#191717" />
                </RelativeLayout>


            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#efefef"

            android:orientation="vertical"

            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/disney_world"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="asasdsa"
                android:textColor="#0b125f"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:background="#efefef"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="320dp">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="160dp"
                    android:background="#a9a9a9">

                </FrameLayout>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:background="#e4e4e4"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                        android:background="#a26262"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/save_upto"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:text="ave_upto"
                            android:textColor="#1c234a"
                            android:textSize="20dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/room_selected"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:text="room_selected"
                            android:textSize="12dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/great_rate"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingLeft="35dp"
                            android:paddingRight="35dp"
                            android:text="great_rate"
                            android:textSize="12dp" />


                    </LinearLayout>


                </RelativeLayout>



            </RelativeLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#a3d5d1ef"
                android:backgroundTintMode="screen"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/more_information"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="safsadf"
                    android:textColor="#1c234a"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/special_saving"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="asdg"
                    android:textColor="#040404"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use **RelativeLayout** or **FrameLayout**. The last child view will overlay everything else.
**FrameLayout** is some kind of view stack. Made for special cases.

**RelativeLayout** is pretty powerful. You can define rules like View A has to align parent layout bottom, View B has to align A bottom to top, etc

As for your question.
In the **LinearLayout** that follows the **FrameLayout** remove the background attribute as its width is **match_parent** as it will cover the **FrameLayout** and also reduce the **layout_marginTop** to **130dp** to get he desired effect of `layout_marginTop=-30dp` and remove the `layout_marginTop=-30dp` from the below LinearLayout.
 which gives you the following

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#676363">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/special_offer"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/special_offer"
                    android:textColor="#f0eaea"
                    android:textSize="25dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/disney_less"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_below="@+id/special_offer"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:shadowColor="#ffffff"
                    android:text="@string/disney_less"
                    android:textColor="#ef6e6e"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/choose_disney"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/disney_less"

                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:text="@string/choose_disney"
                    android:textColor="#eef7e3"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/take_advantage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                    android:paddingStart="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/take_advantage"
                    android:textColor="#191717" />
            </RelativeLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#efefef"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/disney_world"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="@string/common_google_play_services_enable_text"
            android:text="@string/disney_world"
            android:textColor="#0b125f"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:background="#efefef"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="320dp">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:background="#a9a9a9">

            </FrameLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:background="#a26262"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/save_upto"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/save_upto"
                        android:textColor="#1c234a"
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/room_selected"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:text="@string/room_selected"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/great_rate"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="35dp"
                        android:paddingRight="35dp"
                        android:text="@string/great_rate"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#a3d5d1ef"
            android:backgroundTintMode="screen"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/more_information"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/more_information"
                android:textColor="#1c234a"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/special_saving"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/special_saving"
                android:textColor="#040404"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```